# Import typescript file from another folder with another configuration

Tags: typescript, webpack

Suppose we have following folder structure:

```
/folderA
    indexA.ts
    webpackA.config.js
/folderB
    indexB.ts
    webpackB.config.js
```

In both folders I have different webpack configurations. What if I want to import `folderA/index.ts` from `folderB/index.ts`? Something like this:

```
import '../folderA/indexA?config=webpackA.config.js';
```

I need this because I have different aliases in `webpackA.config.js`. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm sure you can achieve what you want, but your question lacks specifics. Please share your webpack config files. So we can see what the problem is.

Comment: @cgTag I need general solution for any config.

Comment: in short, no. You need to have one top level configuration to able to handle those.